# SQL-Select convert to EF linq to entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the fallowing SQL-Select:

```
select * from tlieferschein l 
inner join tbestellung b on l.kbestellung = b.kbestellung 
inner join tkunde k on b.tkunde_kkunde = k.kkunde 
where b.nStorno = 0 
and (select count(*) from tlieferscheinpos x inner join tbestellpos y on x.kbestellpos = y.kbestellpos and x.klieferschein = l.klieferschein) > 0 
and b.cBestellNr = '718' 
order by l.derstellt desc
```

Now, I should convert this sql-select to linq. I have tried the fallowing, but it is not working:

```
var result = from l in context.tLieferschein
   join b in context.tbestellung on l.kBestellung equals b.kBestellung
   join k in context.tkunde on b.tKunde_kKunde equals k.kKunde
   where b.nStorno == 0 && (from x in context.tLieferscheinPos join y in context.tbestellpos on x.kBestellPos equals y.kBestellPos && x.kLieferschein equals l.kLieferschein ).Count() > 0
   orderby l.dErstellt descending
   select new {l, b, k};
```

I hope someone can help me, what I am doing wrong.

This is the first time, I try to write a Linq-Query for Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas everything is fine in your expression except you have missed to add another constraint in where statement which is `b.cBestellNr = '718'`, Add this in you expression and check it again.

For your reference the whole expression would be:

```
var result = from l in context.tLieferschein
   join b in context.tbestellung on l.kBestellung equals b.kBestellung
   join k in context.tkunde on b.tKunde_kKunde equals k.kKunde
   where b.nStorno == 0 && (from x in context.tLieferscheinPos join y in context.tbestellpos on x.kBestellPos equals y.kBestellPos && x.kLieferschein equals l.kLieferschein select new {x, y}).Count() > 0
   && b.cBestellNr == 718
   orderby l.dErstellt descending
   select new {l, b, k};
```

I believe the subquery should be as below:

```
(from x in context.tLieferscheinPos join y in context.tbestellpos 
 on x.kBestellPos.GetValueOrDefault(0) equals Convert.ToInt32(y.kBestellPos) && x.kLieferschein equals l.kLieferschein
 select new {x, y}).Count() > 0
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: There is something wrong with the subselect (for the count) in the where-expression ...

Comment: @ThomasKehl, are you getting any exception or the output doesn't as expected? Also what is the datatype of cBestellNr field?

Comment: I cannot compile it. There seems to be a problem with the join in the subquery. cBestellNr is of type int.

Comment: The problem still exists. This is the Error of the compiler: Error 1 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

Comment: @ThomasKehl, this is related with datatype mismatch. check the fields types of **x.kBestellPos, y.kBestellPos, x.kLieferschein and l.kLieferschein**

Comment: You are right! x.kBestellPos is of int? and y.kBestellPos is of long. Can you help me, what I have to do to solve this?

Comment: @ThomasKehl, Updated the subquery in my answer. Have a look.